# how to test my data is valid or not in vehicle tracking system when data packet is sent by client

Tags: network-programming

1. i am working on vehicle tracking system in which i have to sent data to     server from a separate client.

   2. Data packet are in form of   :"$loc,868182006498858,09122014,052245,1,2655.3338,N,08817.7214,E,25.9,217.39,FE  11,31,8,80,1,LLLL,NNNN,ACTIVE,0.01,0.01,SW6.10,73"
   3. which contains imei no. , longitute, latitude etc which is required by vehile.
   4. i want to test my data which i am sending is valid or not.

Comment: What protocol are you using? CAN, RS-232, or something else?

Comment: i am using: IPV4 protocol

Comment: OK. I assume not only you are using IPv4 but also either UDP or TCP. So the next question is what type of validation you want to do. Are you trying to validate what servers receives is actually what client sends? Is the layer 1 and 2 technology Ethernet?

Comment: No its not Ethernet. I want to know, data which I am sending in data packet i.e. latitude, longitude etc the server accepts it in latitude and longitude form only or in any other form also............

Comment: I suppose you are using an application protocol for tracking system. Can you provide more details in your question?